# Recurrence relation with reciprocal in a circuit

Tags: recurrence-relations, physics, mathematical-physics

The motivation for this recurrence relation is to find the total resistance in this circuit: [image: Axon equivalent circuit model]

Assuming that the capacitor has no resistance, with only one loop of the circuit, (let us suppose) the total resistance amounts to $R_{T_1} = R_o + R_m + R_i$. Then adding on the other loops successively one gets the recurrence relation:
$$R_{T_n} = R_o + R_i + \frac1{R_m^{-1} + R_{T_{n-1}}^{-1}}$$
Computationally I have deduced that the sequence $R_{T_n}$ converges to a certain value. **How would I derive a closed form for the sequence from this recurrence relation, and therefore find the limiting value of the total circuit resistance** (for an infinitely or sufficiently long neuron, not that that exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = R_m$ and $\displaystyle\;\sigma = \frac{R_i + 2R_m + R_o}{R_m}$,  and writing $R_{T_n}$ as $\displaystyle\;A \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ for some $p_n, q_n$ whose overall scale doesn't matter, we have

$$R_{T_{n+1}} = A \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} = \underbrace{A(\sigma-2)}_{R_i+R_o} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{A^{-1}}_{R_m^{-1}} + \underbrace{A^{-1}\frac{q_n}{p_n}}_{R_{T_n}^{-1}}}
\quad\iff\quad
\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}
= \frac{(\sigma-1) p_n + (\sigma-2) q_n}{p_n + q_n}$$
We can transform this to a matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}p_{n+1}\\q_{n+1}\end{bmatrix} \propto
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma-1 & \sigma-2\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}p_{n}\\q_{n}\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is clear the initial condition $R_{T_1} = R_i+R_m+R_o$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{p_1}{q_1} = \sigma-1
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{bmatrix}p_{1}\\q_{1}\end{bmatrix}\propto
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma-1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}\sigma-1 & \sigma-2\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
This implies for any $n > 0$,

$$\begin{bmatrix}p_{n}\\q_{n}\end{bmatrix} 
\propto 
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma-1 & \sigma-2\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^n 
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\sigma-1 & \sigma-2\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ has
eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm}$ and eigenvectors $u_{\pm}$ given by:
$$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac12\left(\sigma \pm \sqrt{\sigma^2-4}\right),
\quad
u_{\pm} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{\pm} -1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Notice

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \propto u_{+} - u_{-}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{bmatrix}p_{n}\\q_{n}\end{bmatrix} \propto \lambda_{+}^n u_{+} - \lambda_{-}^n u_{-}$$
We find

$$R_{T_n} = R_m \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} = R_m
\frac{
\lambda_{+}^n(\lambda_{+} - 1) - 
\lambda_{-}^n(\lambda_{-} - 1)
}{
\lambda_{+}^n - \lambda_{-}^n
}
= R_m \left(\frac{
\lambda_{+}^{n+1} - \lambda_{-}^{n+1}
}{
\lambda_{+}^{n} - \lambda_{-}^n
} - 1\right)
$$
Since $|\lambda_{+}| > 1 > |\lambda_{-}|$, the RHS will be dominated by the $\lambda_{+}$ term when $n$ is large. This implies

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{T_n} = R_m\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_n}{q_n}
= R_m(\lambda_{+} - 1 )
&= \frac12\left( R_i + R_o + \sqrt{(R_i+2R_m+R_o)^2 - 4R_m^2}\right)\\
&= \frac12\left(R_i+R_o + \sqrt{(R_i+R_o)(R_i+R_o+4R_m)}\right)
\end{align}
$$
The same result you will get if you solve the quadratic equation mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to find the limiting value $R_\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} R_{T_n}$, you can just take limits of both sides to deduce that
$$
R_\infty = R_o + R_i + \frac1{R_m^{-1}+R_\infty^{-1}}.
$$
The resulting equation is equivalent to a quadratic equation in $R_\infty$ which can be easily solved.